# Does btGhostObject allow use of complex meshes (not only AABB)?

Tags: c++, bullet

It is sad in its docs:

> The btGhostObject can keep track of all objects that are overlapping By default, this overlap is based on the AABB This is useful for creating a character controller, collision sensors/triggers, explosions etc

Does it mean it is only AABB of its underlying mesh and so detects only collisions with AABB and not complex mesh structure?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference for collision dispatcher between a ghost object and a rigid body: they behave the same way both in broad- and narrow-phase. If you iterate over dispatcher's manifold array, you'll see proper collisions with ghost objects. Documentation refers to the `btGhostObject` internal overlapping objects cache accessible via `getOverlappingObject(int index)` / `getNumOverlappingObjects()` methods. This cache is populated in the broadphase (thus obviously using only AABB), and you have to set the proper pair callback for this to work (`world->getPairCache()->setInternalGhostPairCallback(new btGhostPairCallback);`). You can iterate over this cache in the post-tick and check for the actual collisions.

Comment: That is indeed a wary sad thing. Could you share how to perform actuall body vs body collision detection for ghost object?